# Why are @Configuration and @Service together? What extra are we getting?

Tags: java, spring

Have seen below code. Why we need to use this Configuration and Service annotation together.

```
@Configuration
@Service
public class SomeClass{
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public MongoClient somemethod(@Value){
          .....
       return  mongoClient; 
    }
```

Also `@Bean` default scope is singleton then why again mention

```
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
```

Comment: I assume its just a class that kept growing over its life. `@Service` doesn't do anything when it's already a configuration. At least that's what I would think.

Comment: Thanks @Lino. Why Scope annotation added since Bean default scope is Singleton

Answer (score 1):

@Configuraton and @Service annotations has different purposes. 
***@Configuration*** annotation indicates that a class declares one or more bean methods and may be processed by spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime. 
***@Service*** annotation indicates than an annotated class is a "Business Service Facade" or similar thing.

***Singleton*** is the default scope for a Spring Bean. So it is not necessary to define its scope. However, for better clarity and understanding, you can highlight this fact by using the @Scope annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Service` annotation makes `SomeClass` a bean, whereas the `@Configuration` and `@Bean` are intended to create bean definitions for classes that you did not write(i.e. library classes).

And indeed the default scope is a singleton so the annotation can be ommited.